# How do I use arrays with Alamofire parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I want send arrays using Alamofire.

What I have

```
let params: Parameters = [
            id:job.id ?? 0,
        ]
```

I also have to send array to backend in this format
`jobs[0]=1, jobs[1]=2` etc
my key is jobs[0] and value is 1

This is the equlant on Java

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final int id = job.getPuIds().get(i);
            params.put("job" + "[" + i + "]", String.valueOf(id));
        }
```

How could I do this?

Comment: updated my answer to show code to create your array of ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to print the string you want in swift syntax:

```
for i in 0...jobs.count-1 {
    print("job[\(i)]=\(jobs[i].id)")
}
```

But I think you should try this instead:

Send a dictionary with key "jobs" and the array as the value for that key.

```
var ids = [Int]()
for job in jobs {
        ids.append(job.id)
    }

var params = ["jobs":ids]
```

EDIT: Cleaner code - special thanks to [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander)

```
let params = ["jobs": jobs.map{ $0.id }]
```

Comment: Better to just use `map`: `let params = ["jobs": jobs.map{ $0.id }]`

Comment: omg this answer si so sexy.. sorry.. im just starting with swift.. this is 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Following your implementation in Java, you can do the same in Swift using this:

```
var params: [String:Any] = [:]

for (index, _) in yourArray.enumerated() {
    let id = job.getPuIds()[index]
    params["job[\(index)]", "\(id)"]

}
```

Looking at your implementation I think that I can guess that the `size` variable is based on what is returned in `job.getPuIds()`, in this case the code can be simplified:

```
var params: [String:Any] = [:]

for (index, id) in job.getPuIds().enumerated() {
    params["job[\(index)]", "\(id)"]        
}
```